# Can't make a good mental picture of the electric and magnetic fields of a single moving photon

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

[image]

In most physics textbooks, the oscillating electric and magnetic fields generated by a moving photon are depicted as above.

In this image, the photon is moving along  x axis, the electric field is oscillating long z axis ( in z-x plane), and the magnetic field is oscillating along y axis (in x-y plane).

I am having two fundamental problems with this picture.

1. Does the electric field oscillate strictly in the x-z plane only? Does it completely vanish just a miniscule distance away from this plane? This does not make sense intuitively.
2. If there is just a single photon moving along x axis, the electric and magnetic fields must die out after the photon has passed. This means that the amplitude of E and B at a given point on x axis must fade out as the photon goes away. So how does this picture change in the case of a single moving photon?

Comment: Friendly reminder that comments should be used to improve the question, not to provide brief answers.

Answer (score 22):

The picture does not show the fields of a moving photon. There is no such entity in QED. There is a quantized field whose excited levels can be classified as photons. A coherent superposition of photons may result in a macroscopic electromagnetic field.

What that picture represents are the macroscopic electric and magnetic fields in a plane-wave solution of the classical Maxwell's equations.
The picture requires careful interpretation. It is not a kind of snapshot of the spatial features of the electromagnetic wave. It should be interpreted as a 2D projection of a 3D plot representing the values of the ${\bf E}$ and the ${\bf B}$ fields as a function of the x coordinate in a linearly polarized plane wave. Such plane wave in 3D starts from $x=-\infty$ and arrives at $x=+\infty$. Vectors  ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf B}$ are the same in every plane perpendicular to the $x-$axis, at every distance from the $x-$axis, while their size and orientation periodically vary as functions of $x$. A more faithful representation of the situation described by the plane wave field may be obtained from this [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_plane_wave#/media/File:Linear_Polarization_Linearly_Polarized_Light_plane_wave.svg):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image: Representation of 3D wave nature of electromagnetic field]

Of course, such an infinite object cannot exist. However, real electromagnetic waves can always be represented by a superposition of such unphysical building blocks (Fourier analysis).

There is no possibility of associating such a plane wave to a single photon. One reason is that there is an uncertainty relation between the phase and the number of photons. Therefore, if the number is well defined (one photon), there will be maximum uncertainty for the phase. The picture shows an oscillation with a well definite phase.

Comment: Good answer! Defining a "phase" observable can be tricky, but we can avoid that issue by saying it like this: The number-of-photons observable does not commute with the electric or magnetic field observables, so a photon cannot have well-defined values of the EM fields.

Comment: <quote> " Vectors E and B are the same in every plane perpendicular to the x−axis, at every distance from the x−axis " - Giorgio, so are you saying that E and B move out in concentric circles from origin, like the ripples on the surface of water?

Comment: @dionysus No, E field is uniform in y direction and B is uniform in z direction.

Comment: @dionysus I have added a link to a picture providing a representation of the field of a linear polarized plane wave.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I am a novice to higher physics, and just testing my understanding of foundational concepts, just to see if I have any potential to pursue this line of study.

Comment: I must say, the answers have left me more confused than before. Just to clarify, my question relates to a single photon. Imagine a single, lone-wolf sort of photon blazing through deep space at light speed (pun intended). Now, I understand that quantum physics introduces an element of uncertainty over the position and momentum of the photon. However I believe we still have a sense of the direction of the movement of photon, isn't it? (correct me if I am wrong, please). So, if the photon is traveling in +ve x direction as shown in my picture, does its electric and magnetic fields... (continued)

Comment: vibrate in thin slices as shown in the picture? Do the slices have any "thickness"? Also, how does the amplitude of E and B fade out as one moves away from the location of photon along x axis?

Comment: Giorgio, are you implying that photons and electromagnetic waves are different concepts, and should not be mixed?

Comment: @dionysus That's the point! Photons and em fields are different although related concepts. However, the relation is not that a photon is just a bunch of localized em fields. It is more subtle. Photons can be thought of as the elementary microscopic constituents of what we call em fields at the macroscopic level. Em fields emerge as the collective behavior of a macroscopic number of photons. There is nothing like the em fields associated with a single photon. Many photons *are* the em fields.

Comment: @dionysus I would add that you shouldn't be discouraged by the complexity of the photon concept. Indeed, it is quite a sophisticated concept, but it can be mastered by studying physics step by step. Unfortunately, popsci has the tendency to present complex concepts in an apparently familiar way, at the risk of  paving the way to misconceptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127239/discussion-between-dionysus-and-giorgiop).